# Why this examples of `zip()` code have different outputs?

Tags: python, python-itertools

As far, as I am able to understand, we are unpacking 3 identical iterators in both cases, but output is different.
In first case, it, for some reason, similar to `list(zip(c[::3], c[1::3], c[2::3]))`, in second, it behaves like normal `zip()`.

```
c = [[a, b] for a, b in itertools.product(list(range(3)), list(range(3)))]

# first example
list(zip(*[iter(c)] * 3))
>[([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]), ([1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]), ([2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2])]

# second example
list(zip(*[iter(c), iter(c), iter(c)]))
>[([0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]),
 ([0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]),
 ([0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 2]),
 ([1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]),
 ([1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]),
 ([1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]),
 ([2, 0], [2, 0], [2, 0]),
 ([2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1]),
 ([2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2])]
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: best choice: `list(zip(*(iter(c) for _ in range(3))))`

Comment: First shares references to the same iterator.  The second has separate iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your first example is the same as

```
it = iter(c)
print(list(zip(*[it, it, it])))  # == list(zip(it, it, it))
```

this is not the same as your second example `list(zip(iter(c), iter(c), iter(c))` where you create 3 fresh iterators.

every time `next` is called on `it` this has an influence on what happens the next time `it` is used.

in the second example the  3 iterators run independently.